# subl command does not invoke the editor unless cmd.exe was ran as administrator

Tags: windows-10, sublime-text-3, sublime-text, non-admin

On my Windows 10 system, when I open a regular terminal (cmd.exe), I cannot edit files using the subl command:

```
subl myfile.txt
```

The command does not do anything, I did not get any error message. However, when I opened the terminal as administrator, then subl works as expected. Is there a way for subl to work in non-administrator terminal?

#### My Environment

- Windows 10
- *C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\subl.exe* is in the path in both terminals

Comment: where is the txt file located? if also in C:\Program Files\ it is by design, that you need admin permissions to write the file

Comment: *myfile.txt* is in my home directory where I have write permission.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: No error message, it does not do anything, a **no-op**